# PerlのCGIモジュールでHTMLからのパラメーター渡しを行いたい

Tags: html, perl

PerlのCGIモジュールでHTMLフォームの表示を行おうとしております。
下記の引用部分でどのようにparamを使ったらよいのでしょうか？
質問の意味も通じるのか不安なのですが、ご教示いただけると助かります。よろしくお願い致します。

- Windows 7 Professional SP1 64ビット
- Apache 2.4.29(Win64)
- Perl v5.24.3
- Google Chrome バージョン: 63.0.3239.132（Official Build） （64 ビット）

## HTML側

```
<html>
　<head>
    <title>Form Sample</title>
　</head>

  <body>
    <h1>Web Page</h1></body>

    <form action="/cgi/01input.cgi" method="POST" >
        Value 1:<input name="v1" type="text" value=""><br>
        Value 2:<input name="v2" type="text" value="">
        <input type="submit"  value="送信">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Perl側

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI;

my $cr = "\n" ;
my %in ;
my $alldata ;

if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq 'POST')
    { read(STDIN, $alldata, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});}
   else { $alldata = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};}    

foreach my $data (split(/&/, $alldata)) {
    my ($key, $value) = split(/=/, $data);

  $value =~ tr/+//;
  $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack('C', hex($1))/eg;
  $value =~ s/\t//g;

  $in{"$key"} = $value;
}


my $q = new CGI;

print $q->header();
print $q->start_html(-title=>'test');
print $q->start_form(-method=>'POST',-action=>'02input.cgi');
```

> ```
> foreach my $key(sort keys(%in)){
>    print "$key:<input type=text name='$key' value=$in{$key}><br>$cr";
> }
> ```

```
print $q->end_form;
print $q->end_html;

exit;
```

***追加
paramで受け取りたいのですが、下記の引用部分をparamでのCGIモジュールの内容に修正し、localhostで見ると、ブランクページとなってしまいます。
htmlソースで見ると下記のとおりの状態となっています。

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="02input.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: formの <input name="v1"> を paramで読み出したいならmy $v1 = $q->param('v1');　です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML側のformタグでCGIのパスが以下の様になっていますが、パスの頭に`/`が付いているのが余計な気がします。

```
<form action="/cgi/01input.cgi" method="POST">
```

仮に以下の構成だとすると

```
http://localhost/01form.html
http://localhost/cgi/01input.cgi
```

HTMLから見た正しい相対パスは、`cgi/01input.cgi`となるはずです。

```
<form action="cgi/01input.cgi" method="POST">
```

なお、webサーバの設定次第ですが一般的には`cgi/`ではなく`cgi-bin/`に保存するので、こちらもパスの記述ミスが無いか確認してみてください。

---

蛇足ですが、CGI側は単に受け取ったデータを表示するだけなら`$q->start_form`の行は不要なはずです。質問文に書かれている例はCGIが自分自身を呼び出してデータを表示する場合の記述方法です。